# Member component of a form destruction in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a project in C#/Windows Forms, where I have a simple form with a `PictureBox` that i draw images to from a background thread. If I close the form while drawing is active the background thread crashes when trying to perform invoke to update the bitmap, which is quite logical. I tried putting an `AutoResetEvent` that  the destructor would wait on, so that destructor would not return until all drawing is done and the background thread knows it is supposed to exit. But I concluded that the crash happens before destructor is executed so I started to wonder, at what point are the components of the form destroyed? I assume that before the destructor? So what is a safe place to wait for the drawing to finish? Override `Dispose()` and do it there?

Comment: Did you try the Dispose?

Comment: Why would you want to stop disposing when the user closes the form?

Comment: @helgeheldre, I don't want to stop, I just want to wait till background thread has finished drawing and then resume and dispose everything

Comment: @AmiramKorach, well that seems to work now, but I wanted someone to clear my mind, if that is the right way

Comment: @Rudolfs Bundulis: I took the opposite approach... My thinking was, I didn't want to wait for a painting I don't want to see... I mean, I closed the form, right? So close already. So my background animator (i.e. painter) just eats the "you tried to access the disposed form" exception (I forget the exact exception type) and exits the background thread... it's simple and it works, and it is, IMHO, robust enough... eating a generic Exception is allways evil, however sometimes eating a specific-type-of-Exception is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what I would think, there is already a `Dispose(bool disposing)` method in the Designer file e.g. `MainForm.Designer.cs`.

I would put some code to close/finish the background thread in the beginning of that method. And a `AutoResetEvent` or a `ManualResetEvent` would be a good way to do it.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm doing now, and looks like it is the right way, thanks for clearing that up.